# Future<List<List<News>>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<dynamic>

Tags: flutter

I am getting this error when I try to assign the values that retrieved from `firestore` to a `List` in `flutter`

This method retrieves the data:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:snap_news_ctse_2020/banuka/model/news_model.dart';

class FireStoreServiceApi {
  static final FireStoreServiceApi _fireStoreService =
      FireStoreServiceApi._internal();
  Firestore _db = Firestore.instance;

  FireStoreServiceApi._internal();

  factory FireStoreServiceApi() {
    return _fireStoreService;
  }

  // get the news
  Stream<List<News>> getNews() {
    return _db.collection("news").snapshots().map(
          (snapshot) => snapshot.documents
              .map((doc) => News.fromMap(doc.data, doc.documentID))
              .toList(),
        );
  }

}
```

And this is where I call it and assign to a `List`

```
  Stream<List<News>> stream = FireStoreServiceApi().getNews();

  stream.toList();

  var banuka = [];

  banuka = stream;
```

[Update]

This is the `News` model:

```
class News {
  final String headline;
  final String description;
  final String imageUrl;
  final String timeNews;
  final String timeDate;
  final String priority;


  News({this.headline,this.description, this.imageUrl, this.timeNews, this.timeDate, this.priority});

  News.fromMap(Map<String,dynamic> data, String id):
    headline=data['headline'], 
    description=data['description'], 
    imageUrl=data['imageUrl'],
    timeNews=data['timeNews'],
    timeDate=data['timeDate'],
    priority=data['priority'];

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap(){
    return {
      "headline" : headline,
      "description": description,
      "imageUrl": imageUrl,
      "timeNews": timeNews,
      "timeDate": timeDate,
      "priority": priority
    };
  }
}
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: provide the proper error message or screenshot of error and also give the News class code because you can not directly use `stream.toList();` in above code.

Comment: Proper error is mentioned in the title of this question.

Comment: Im' not sure but try forecasting: 
return _db.collection("news").snapshots().map(
          (snapshot) => snapshot.documents
              .map((doc) => News.fromMap(doc.data, doc.documentID))
              .toList(),
        ) as List<News>;

Comment: @aldobaie no, still no luck

Comment: I believe it has to do with  News.fromMap. because data is probably list<dynamic>. Could you show us  News.fromMap function

Comment: can you try. this? _db
        .collection("news")
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) => snapshot.documents
            .map((doc) => News.fromMap(doc.data, doc.documentID)))
        .toList();

Comment: @aldobaie i have updated the question. Can you check?